# Force Content Down with Mobile CSS Nav

Tags: css, mobile, navigation, responsive

when resizing the window beneath 680px the nav converts to a mobile version, however when you click the dropdown the content beneath does not get pushed down. I have tried changing the height values to auto, adding clearing divs beneath the nav etc but to no avail. Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp

Comment: it doesn't, that is what I followed and have already looked at various Google results.

Comment: You have used custom height on ul in so many places. Remove them and adjust according to screen and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places where the nav height is being defined. If all of those are removed, as seen in the image below, the content will push down when the menu expands. It looks like the primary nav needs to have a height of 62px when closed and auto when open.

[image]

Comment: unchecked all the ones in your screenshot but still it doesn't seem to push the content down?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolute property set on one of your ul elements. http://screencast.com/t/TnHFF5JYF 
Change that to relative, and this will lead you in the right direction.